# PHP, AJAX метод GET

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

Здравствуйте! Хотел реализовать пошаговую форму на подобие [**ссылка**](https://www.icracked.com/repair).
Понравилась реализация выбора девайсов. Подскажите пожалуйста направление как сделать такое. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так. Первым делом все данные лежат в базе. Рисуем кнопку и в цикле AJAXом подгружаем. На каждую кнопку вешаешь onclick и AJAX функцией передаешь параметры на дальнейшую категорию. Предыдущие кнопки jquery удаляешь и рисуешь навые опять. Плюс анимацией добавляешь полосу загрузки. И так далее. Это самое простое что можно сделать